# how to start jboss5.1 using windows services on network

Tags: windows-services, jboss5.x

I have start jboss5.1.0GA with windows services. But but it execute only on local machine .
I want to run it on a network . please help me for solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Expose your system to network
2. Do not run the service as localhost, rather run your service by
       binding your ip **(-b option)**

Then you will see your jboss-server exposed to the network

Answer (score 0):

cmd:

```
sc \\[your.server] start JBAS50SVC
```

That's the default name for the service, if you registered it from the \bin using jbosssvc.exe

If that doesn't work, check the service name registered in the windows services list and amend accordingly.